# How to configure ID parameters in django_rest_framework APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

My goal is to specify behavior that allows me to enter an ID into my URL.

Currently, I am able to send GET, PUT, and PATCH requests to the URL 'localhost:8000/api/players/?id=#' where the hash represents player id

I would like to update my code to understand that if I send a GET/PUT/PATCH request to 'localhost:8000/api/players/2' that I am looking for a player with id=2

my models.py

```
class player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

my serializer.py

```
class playerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = player
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'team', 'position', 'number']
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework. serializers import Serializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from main.models import player
from .serializers import playerSerializer
import json


class playerList(APIView):

    serializer_class = playerSerializer
    throttle_scope = "main_app"

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        players = player.objects.all()
        return players

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):     
        try:
            id = request.query_params["id"]
            if id != None:
                player_object = player.objects.get(id=id)
                serializer = playerSerializer(player_object)
        except:
            players = self.get_queryset()
            serializer = playerSerializer(players, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        player_data = request.data
        new_player = player.objects.create(
            first_name=player_data['first_name'],
            last_name=player_data['last_name'],
            team=player_data['team'],
            position=player_data['position'],
            number=player_data['number']
        )
        new_player.save()

        serializer = playerSerializer(new_player)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = request.query_params["id"]
        player_object = player.objects.get(id=id)

        data = request.data

        player_object.first_name = data["first_name"]
        player_object.last_name = data["last_name"]
        player_object.team = data["team"]
        player_object.position = data["position"]
        player_object.number = data["number"]

        player_object.save()

        serializer = playerSerializer(player_object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = request.query_params["id"]
        player_object = player.objects.get(id=id)

        data = request.data

        player_object.first_name = data.get('first_name', player_object.first_name)
        player_object.last_name = data.get('last_name', player_object.last_name)
        player_object.team = data.get('team', player_object.team)
        player_object.position = data.get('position', player_object.position)
        player_object.number = data.get('number', player_object.number)

        player_object.save()
        serializer = playerSerializer(player_object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('players', playerList.as_view()),
]
```

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days... any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Austin H

Comment: Can you also share your urls.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly suggest using DRF's [**`viewsets`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) as it will cover most of the things that you need here with little code. But if you want to play around it yourself with your current view:

First you have to define another url that accepts the player id, while keeping the old url to preserve the current behavior your want:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('players/<int:pk>', playerList.as_view()),
    url('players', playerList.as_view()),
]
```

`players/<int:pk>` will support urls like `players/1` and pass `1` as a keyword argument `pk` in the view.

You can then change your view to something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class playerList(APIView):
    ...

    def get_object(self, id)
        return get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), id=id)

    def get(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):     
        id = pk or request.query_params.get('id')
        if id:
            serializer = playerSerializer(self.get_object(id))
        else:
            serializer = playerSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def put(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        player_object = self.get_object(pk or request.query_params.get('id'))
        ...
    
    def patch(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        player_object = self.get_object(pk or request.query_params.get('id'))
        ...
```

```
id = pk or request.query_params.get('id')
```

This means that if `pk` was not passed (i.e. the url used was not `players/1`) then the view will just do the old behavior you have by getting the id from `request.query_params`. This is also why `pk=None` is set, in case we get the id from the query params. Also note that `post` needs to also capture `args` and `kwargs`.

Answer (score 2):

views.py

```
class playerList(APIView):

    serializer_class = playerSerializer
    throttle_scope = "main_app"
    

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):     
        try:
            # id = request.query_params["id"]
            id = self.kwargs["id"]
              if id != None:
                player_object = player.objects.get(id=id)
                serializer = playerSerializer(player_object)
        except:
            players = self.get_queryset()
            serializer = playerSerializer(players, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        player_data = request.data
        new_player = player.objects.create(
            first_name=player_data['first_name'],
            last_name=player_data['last_name'],
            team=player_data['team'],
            position=player_data['position'],
            number=player_data['number']
        )
        new_player.save()

        serializer = playerSerializer(new_player)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #id = request.query_params["id"]
        id = self.kwargs["id"]
        player_object = player.objects.get(id=id)

        data = request.data

        player_object.first_name = data["first_name"]
        player_object.last_name = data["last_name"]
        player_object.team = data["team"]
        player_object.position = data["position"]
        player_object.number = data["number"]

        player_object.save()

        serializer = playerSerializer(player_object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #id = request.query_params["id"]
        id = self.kwargs["id"]
        player_object = player.objects.get(id=id)

        data = request.data

        player_object.first_name = data.get('first_name', player_object.first_name)
        player_object.last_name = data.get('last_name', player_object.last_name)
        player_object.team = data.get('team', player_object.team)
        player_object.position = data.get('position', player_object.position)
        player_object.number = data.get('number', player_object.number)

        player_object.save()
        serializer = playerSerializer(player_object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('players/<int:id>/', playerList.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).